# probability that all players score

Tags: probability

The top 3 foul shooters on the basketball team last season were Kiah and Moriah and Stefanie with foul shooting percentages of 0.600, 0.575 and 0.564, respectively.  If in a particular game each of these players get an “and one” and goes to the line one time, what is the probability that all three players make their foul shots?

Comment: *and one*: The free throw awarded to a shooter who is fouled while scoring. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_basketball_terms

Answer (score 3):

The probability is  $0.6\cdot0.574\cdot0.564\approx 0.194$ You can imagine the players are defective coins which are more likely to land on tails.